# display comments from comments with replys system

Tags: php, sql

**Database structure:**

```
TABLE cmts

| id | article_id | reply_id | name | comment |
-----------------------------------------------
| 1  |     3      |     0    | .... | ....... |
| 2  |     3      |     1    | .... | ....... |
| 3  |     3      |     2    | .... | ....... |
| 4  |     3      |     3    | .... | ....... |
| 5  |     3      |     0    | .... | ....... |
| 6  |     3      |     0    | .... | ....... |
```

My problem is to display it with PHP, I mean how to write a loop which brings me the desirable structure of the comments:

```
comment
    reply
        reply
            reply 
comment 
comment
```

**REMEMBER:** 'reply to reply' is UNLIMITED. and here is my problem.

In addition, is the database structure fine? to be sure you understand, when `reply_id = 0` the meaning is that it is independent comment.

Thank your guys.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to adopt a parent/child comment system so that you can both reply to actual comments and sub-comments

By this I mean you can reply to a reply?

Then with this do a MYSQL QUERY with a WHILE (to only display parent comments) - this while will list all parent comments

Within your while you should then do another QUERY and WHILE for replies to that comment
(Where reply_id = comment id) - this will display all child comments and also

And another query and while to check for replies to child comment (which will list replies to that) replies WHERE the reply_id = child comment id (within the child while)

Your current database should do the job :)

Probably easier ways of doing it mind you.